# got error while i deploying my adf application 12c on weblogic server 12c

Tags: weblogic12c, jdeveloper

I'm trying to deploy my adf App using jdeveloper 1.2.2.4.0 on weblogic server 1.2.2.4.0 so when i deploy ear file i got this error:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Error: Unresolved Webapp Library references for "WebAppModule(MyApp_ViewController_webapp:MyApp_ViewController_webapp.war)", defined in weblogic.xml [Extension-Name: adf.oracle.domain.webapp, exact-match: false]
```

[image]

Comment: Your web application depends on a shared library (adf.oracle.domain.webapp) which is not deployed in your WebLogic Server instance. Deploy it first and the deploy your application

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin do you mean by that i need to install adf runtime inside weblogic server!

Comment: yes  as it is required by your web application

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin I installed fmw_12.2.1.4.0_infrastructure and it didn't work!

Comment: that's not enough. You have to create a fmw domain and not just a WebLogic Server domain.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue,@Emmanual Colin can you please provide an example?